# LinearLayout horizontal gravity setGravity() not working programmatically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am trying to set the gravity of a linearlayout container through code using conatiner.setGravity().
But it is not working however when done through xml it is working.
Below is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/chat_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/messengerImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:maxWidth="24dp"
        android:maxHeight="24dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bubble" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="85dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:maxWidth="250sp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/message_fav"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/chat_message_fav_selector"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The code used is:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
holder.container.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

This is for a chat application setting a container to left when the other person sends the message and to right when sent by the user.

Comment: You could have used `holder.container.setGravity(Gravity.Center)`

Comment: Not working.....

Comment: please try to check your ViewHolder Class,are at `ViewHolder class` you set right id for `holder.container`? like: `container = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.chat_containe);`

Comment: Yes.
Crossed checked it.

Comment: I have set match parent but still gravity right has no effect it always starts from left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

change the width of `chat_container` `wrap_content` to `match_parent`

```
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Remember  gravity only works where there is extra space in parent layout.

Comment: Won't match_parent remove the extra space?
In that case the layout_gravty won't work at all

Comment: when you use `wrap_content`  your layout size is as per their child so there will be no extra space child can't move any where.

Comment: I get your point.
Setting the gravity instead of layout_gravity aligns the children accordingly to the gravity.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in xml code you set layout_gravity="left" for Linearlayout.
but in java code you try to set gravity.
gravity and layout_gravity are different.
in java code you can do this to set gravity :

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
    linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

lp.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)

Comment: I need to shift it to the right.
Also,
This is not working.

Comment: remove this code first  :  LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
holder.container.setLayoutParams(lp);                                       Then try adding code like : lp.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT)

Comment: @Vishal try lp.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.RIGHT)